# Chopped-off elementor button at top right and bottom left

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I want to make Elementor button look like this

[chopped-off corners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWz8S.png)

I want to but the code in the button custom CSS tab, not in the WordPress back end

I tried write the code with chatgpt, but it doesn't work

help me pls....

Comment: Have you investigated clip-path? Have a go at coding this and if still stuck put your code into the question with a description of the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score -1):

Here is the solution with CSS pseudo elements(:before and :after).

```css
        .chopped-button{
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            color: #24303b;
            background-color: #ceb77d;
            border: solid 8px #606060;
            padding: 15px 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 500;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: relative;
        }
        .chopped-button:before{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            left: -20px;
            bottom: -20px;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #606060;
            transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
        .chopped-button:after{
            content: '';
            position: absolute;
            right: -20px;
            top: -20px;
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: #606060;
            transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button class="chopped-button">Chopped Button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer
but can you tell me where I'll but the HTML code?

Comment: you can simply add CSS I create on your button or anchor tag, and it will wok fine.